# CRM Email Plug in

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have created a plugin using the CRM SDK which gets an attchment from a CRM annotation and emails it to a user. 
The code I have written works well when running locally within a web app but once I run it as a published plugin the email looses the attachment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which CRM are you talking about?

Comment: What SDK in what language or on what platform?

Comment: Sorry its CRM 4.0. The SDK is CRM's built web service. All code is in C#

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean as a published plugin? how else were you testing it, do you mean a different deployment i.e. IFD / On Premise?

i would check the trace logs and see if the plugin has caused an errror, also make sure how the plugin is authenticating - who is it being run as and whether they have the necessary permissions.